# How does a user with less than 3k reputation see the closes votes count?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There was a question where the OP had 1307 rep point and knew the close votes count on the question but I thought users do not see that until they're [3k+](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

How did he know the close count?

Comment: OP can see close votes on their own question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) for OP to view/cast close votes on their own questions. This privilege requires only 250 reputation.

Comment: yep got it now thanks.